# how to combine multiple formgroup and post to one api using mat stepper in angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular8, mat-stepper

Im using mat-stepper of Angular Material design library.

I use 4 separate FormGroups. I would send informations of first 3 formGroup to combine and 4 is separate. in 3rd stage on clicking the submit button 3 formGroups to be combined and send to a one api and the 4th formgroup family detailas to be send to the another api. and the  there is any solution to this.. thanks for advance

```
 firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
  secondFormGroup: FormGroup;
  thirdFormGroup: FormGroup;
  fourthFormGroup: FormGroup;
  rows: FormArray;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firstFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      name : ['', Validators.required],
      gender : ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.secondFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      permanentHouseName: ['', Validators.required],
      permanentHouseNumber: ['', Validators.required],
      permanentPlace: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.thirdFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      profession  : ['', Validators.required],
      designation  : ['', Validators.required],
    });
    this.fourthFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      items: [null],
      items_value: ['no']
    });
        this.rows = this.formBuilder.array([]);

        this.fourthFormGroup.addControl('rows', this.rows);
        this.onAddRow()

  }
  form1(){
    console.log(this.firstFormGroup.value)
  }
  form2(){
    console.log(this.secondFormGroup.value)
  } 
  form3(){
    console.log(this.thirdFormGroup.value)
  }
  onSubmit(){

  }
  form4(){
    console.log("value",this.fourthFormGroup.value)
    console.log("array",this.rows.value)
  }

  onAddRow() {
    this.rows.push(this.createItemFormGroup());
  }
  onRemoveRow(rowIndex:number){
    this.rows.removeAt(rowIndex);
  }

  createItemFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      name: null,
      age: null,
      relation: null
    });
  }
```

template

```
   <mat-horizontal-stepper labelPosition="bottom" #stepper>
        <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup" errorMessage="Personal Details are required.">
         <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="form1()" #formone="ngForm">
            <ng-template matStepLabel>Details</ng-template>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm" >
                    <input type="text"  class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Applicant Name Here ..." formControlName="name" required>                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm" >
                    <input type="radio" value="male" formControlName="gender" checked required>  Male &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="radio" value="female" formControlName="gender" required>  Female &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="radio" value="others" formControlName="gender" required>  Others
                </div>                
            </div>             
            <br>
            <div style="text-align: right;">
                <button class="btn btn-success" style="width: 250px;" mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
              </div>
         </form>
        </mat-step>
        <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup" errorMessage="Address is required.">
            <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="form2()" #formtwo="ngForm">
                <ng-template matStepLabel>Address</ng-template>
                <br>
                <div>
                    1. Permanent Address
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm" >
                        <input type="text"  class="form-control"  placeholder="House Name ..." formControlName="permanentHouseName" required>                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm" >
                        <input type="text"  class="form-control"  placeholder="House Number ..." formControlName="permanentHouseNumber" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm" >
                        <input type="text"  class="form-control"  placeholder="Place ..." formControlName="permanentPlace" required>  
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div style="text-align: right;">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" style="width: 250px;" mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button class="btn btn-success" style="width: 250px;" mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </mat-step>
        <mat-step [stepControl]="thirdFormGroup" errorMessage="Profession Details are required.">
            <form [formGroup]="thirdFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="form3()" #formthree="ngForm">
                <ng-template matStepLabel>Profession Details</ng-template>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm" style=" font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans'">
                        <input type="text"  class="form-control"  placeholder="Profession ..." formControlName="profession" required>                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm" style=" font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans'">
                        <input type="text"  class="form-control"  placeholder="Designation ..." formControlName="designation" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm" style=" font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans'">
                        <!-- <input type="text"  class="form-control"  placeholder="Designation ..." formControlName="thirdCtrl" required> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()" style="width: 250px;" >Submit</button>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div style="text-align: right;">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" style="width: 250px;" mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button class="btn btn-success" style="width: 250px;" mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </mat-step>  
        <mat-step [stepControl]="fourthFormGroup" errorMessage="Family details are required.">
            <form [formGroup]="fourthFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="form4()" #formfour="ngForm">
                <ng-template matStepLabel>Family Details </ng-template>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div *ngIf="fourthFormGroup.get('rows')">
                    <div class="row " *ngFor="let row of fourthFormGroup.get('rows')?.controls;let index = index;">
                        <div class="col-sm" style=" font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans'">
                          <input type="text" [formControl]="row.get('name')" name="" class="form-control"  placeholder="Name Type Here ...">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm" style=" font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans'">
                          <input type="text" [formControl]="row.get('age')" name="" class="form-control"  placeholder="Age Type Here ...">
                      </div>
                    <div class="col-sm" style=" font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans'">
                        <input type="text" [formControl]="row.get('relation')" name="" class="form-control"  placeholder="No.Of Days To Complete Type Here ...">
                    </div>
                      <div class="col-" style=" font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans'">
                          <input type="submit" name="" value="+" (click)="onAddRow()"  class="pink_button_square" style="float: right; width: 50px;" [disabled]="this.message>=100">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-" style=" font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans'">
                          <input type="submit" name="" value="-" (click)="onRemoveRow(index)" class="pink_button_square" style="float: right; width: 50px;" [disabled]="this.rows.length==1">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                <br>
                <div style="text-align: right;">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" style="width: 250px;" mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button class="btn btn-success" style="width: 250px;" mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </mat-step>       
        <mat-step>
            <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
            <p>You are now done.</p>
            <div >
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" style="width: 250px;" mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button class="btn btn-danger" style="width: 250px;" mat-button (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
            </div>
        </mat-step>
  </mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

stackblits example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rcotij